# UITabBar navigation and presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have UITabBar based navigation and want always tabbar on top other widows. In one controller i have method which opens other controller, but when i use this UITabBar disappear.
What i should do more ?

```
ThirdView*third =[[ThirdView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
third.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:third animated:YES];
[third release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `UINavigationController`s for the tabs of your `UITabBarController`. Then to present a new `UIViewController` you want to push new it onto the stack of your `UINavigationController`. You can do this like so:

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourController
>   animated:YES];

If you want the modal effect, you could do something like this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

 CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation]; transition.duration = 0.4f;
 transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
 transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
 [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                 forKey:kCATransition]
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:NO];
```

Comment: But i don't want to use pushViewController, this works normal. but what if presentModalViewController ? UItabbar still disappear

Comment: A modal view controller would be intended to lay on top of the UITabBarController. A UINavigationController would be more suitable for your needs. You could also do something like this